# how to augment precision of date difference in oracle

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g

I have to handle this ultraprecise date difference.

In a stored procedure:

```
d1 := abs(q.date - p.date);
-- renders .00001157407407407407407407407407407407407407

d2 := abs(z.date - p.date);                  
-- renders .00001157407407407407407407407407407407407407 (the same value assigned to d1)
```

But i know that d1 is slightly different from d2. Something in the likes of:

real d1: .00001157407407407407407407407407407407407407001

real d2: .00001157407407407407407407407407407407407407002

Is there a way to augment oracle's numeric precision of d1 and d2?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Oracle `date` has precision to the second.  Subtracting two dates gives a difference in terms of days.  1 day = 24 hours = 24*60 (1440) minutes = 1440*60 (86400) seconds.  So the smallest possible difference between two `date` values is 1/86400 = 1.157 * 10^-5 (0.00001157) days.  It isn't possible for two date differences to vary by less than that.

It appears, therefore, that your problem is not one of numeric precision but one of `date` precision.  You could change your `date` columns to `timestamp` columns which can store up to nanosecond precision though Oracle can only get millisecond (Window) or microsecond (Unix) precision from the operating system.  That would give you much finer resolution in the time components that you are storing.

Comment: so i guess that the periodic 407 is just oracle going bananas after the 8th decimal. that repetition seemed suspicious from the beginning... Cannot change field types because a third party software we are using does not handle timestamp. Gonna try casting dates to timestamps before performing the substraction. Would you suggest something else? thank you

Comment: @PrefijoSustantivo - Casting won't help you.  If you do the math, the two differences that you show are both 1/86400 (I didn't try to represent the full decimal representation, I was just pointing out that is the smallest possible difference).  You as a human may know that there were milliseconds between the two dates but the application never captured that so Oracle has no way to report on any difference smaller than a second.